# Why does my counter doesnt do my desired sequence?

Tags: integrated-circuit, counter, multisim

Hey there guys i have to built up a counter with the following sequence : 1-2-5-6-7-8-11-12-15, my Multisim schematics works like a charm, but when i'm about to build it on my breadboard it doesn't really works, IC's are ok and the circuit is right builded

Is there something that's needed other the ones mentioned ??

I can't really figure out the reason it doeasn't work

Schematic : [image]

[image]

I'm using 2 JK flip flop IC's(4 JK),3 AND GATES, 1 OR and a 555 Timer[image]

Comment: While it's great that you're trying to learn and build things, this approach and question have many problems.  Your breadboard is haphazardly wired, which makes the picture near meaningless for showing anything but that fact.  Your schematic has far too many overlapping wires, and so provides no clear display of the design intent of how you imagined this would work.  As a result, it's very hard to tell if you have something like a logic/timing hazard, or if you have an implementation error.   You also entirely neglect to explain what it does do, and how that differs from intent.

Comment: All that can really be said is a general suggestion to neaten things up, and to start at the beginning and follow the signal states through the circuit and understand at what point they stop reflecting your goal.   Also note that there has been no reason to breadboard something of this complexity with logic chips for at least a decade, if not two - most tasks (especially those slow enough to work on a breadboard) are done by small microcontrollers, with the fast ones done using logic described not by a schematic but by a Hardware Description Language and implemented in an FPGA, CPLD, or ASIC.

Comment: You will probably find your question closed fairly shortly. You have given almost no useful information. "It doesn't really works" tells us nothing. Oh yes, and you need to learn how to drive LEDs with TTL.  Use pulldown, not pullup. And if it works in simulation but not in reality, your claim that " the circuit is right builded" is obviously incorrect. Here's a start. Provide 1 0.1 uF ceramic cap from ground to +5 for each IC, as close to the IC as possible and not using jumper wires.

Comment: Your schematic would be much easier to understand if you drew individual gates and flip-flops, rather than the boxes representing the whole IC.

Comment: Oh i've done that, give me a sec i'll attach it

Comment: You still haven't told us what  "It doesn't really works" means.

Comment: I would make things easier for you and make a document with the wire colors and then build the breadboard with the same colors,

Comment: your schematic is just as bad as the picture of the breadboard .... it needs a lot of cleaning up

Comment: LEDs need a lot of current to light. And you're using some outputs to drive both a LED and as input for other ICs. At a minimum this makes the signal slow to change. At worst this causes the signal to flutter or not reach the required level to register at all. Check the current rating for the outputs that they can even drive the LEDs. I recommend driving all LEDs with dedicated NOT gates with the LEDs connected towards Vcc instead of GND. This isolates the big current draw from the logic circuits, utilizes the stronger sink current (pulling towards GND) of TTL ICs and LEDs light on 1.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in comments, the "schematic" is really a wiring diagram, not what would be generally called a schematic, and that makes it very difficult (e.g. hours of work) for someone to reverse-engineer back to a *real* schematic.

So instead of that, I'll give some general comments to help you with this, or in future similar tasks:

> my Multisim schematics works like a charm, but when i'm about to build it on my breadboard it doesn't really works

That is a classic indication that your simulator is not simulating *something* from real-world electronics, **if** your breadboard wiring really is the same as the (claimed working) simulation. In your case, some obvious concerns are:

- Using TTL outputs to try to source enough current to light LEDs

  Unlike CMOS outputs which typically have near-symmetric sink/source drive capabilities, many general TTL outputs have comparatively weak source capabilities (bus drivers and similar TTL can be exceptions).

  The [TI 74LS76 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn5476.pdf) shows the specification is a 16mA sink capability (i.e. if your LED and series resistor were connected between Vcc and the output pin) with a typical V<sub>OL</sub> = 0.2V at that 16ma load, but only a **0.4mA** source capability (if the LED and series resistor were connected between the output pin and Gnd, as in your schematic) with a typical V<sub>OH</sub> = 3.4V at that 0.4mA load.

  Depending on your LED colour and type, that difference in sink vs. source current drive capability can be the difference between the LED lighting or not.

  If your simulator doesn't know and correctly simulate that difference in current capability, then that could be one reason why the simulation (apparently) shows correct behaviour, but the real world doesn't.
- Decoupling capacitors

  Your simulator wiring diagram shows none. Your breadboard photo isn't clear, but I don't think there are any. Missing decoupling capacitors (or those fitted far from the ICs) can especially affect counter ICs. You can start by adding 0.1uF ceramic caps *immediately next to each TTL IC* and a 100uF (or larger) bulk electrolytic where the power supply connects to the breadboard.

  Also, be aware that the bipolar 555 timer is *notorious* for putting noise onto its supply rail (which, according to your diagram, is shared with the logic ICs!). Read its datasheet (and previous questions on this site) for specific decoupling recommendations, which are *in addition* to the decoupling for each TTL IC.

  This is a topic for you to research. There have been many relevant questions about decoupling capacitors on this site, which you can read.

And finally: Don't do a "big bang" construction i.e. don't assemble everything, and *then* test it. That's because as you have now seen, when the *whole* design has been constructed and doesn't work when first tested, you now have a large job to find the cause (or cause**s** - there might be multiple problems).

Instead, build and test incrementally e.g. power supply first; then add the clock source and confirm correct operation using an oscilloscope or logic probe etc.; then add one or two ICs at a time, testing as you go.

Then when something doesn't work as it should, your investigation can focus quickly on what has changed between when the circuit last *did* work correctly, and when it first *stopped* working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So,after some research on decoupling caps,and tips about TTL "powering",i've finally managed to materialize the needed counter and i'll pass the exams of my university on this subject,i'm so grateful i've out found about this site and the help you provided

Thanks a TON ! :D

Counter Samples :

[image: Number 1]

[image: Number 2]

[image: Number 5]

Comment: glad you were able to work it out

Comment: one of the things that you have to learn in electronics is to think clearly about what you wish to achieve, and to think clearly about the information that is in front of you and what the information actually means to you and to others. .... if you think about the three pictures that you posted, you will realize that they do not show anything useful to anyone other than you, therefore they are meaningless here

Comment: Oh ok i get that but the reason i posted them is to show that the counter actually works,starts with the numbers 1,2,5(like the pictures) and it goes up to the final value correctly, that's all :P

Comment: the pictures do not show that at all .... the pictures are not documented, therefore useless ..... like i said before, they have meaning only to you .... the sooner you realize that, the sooner you will start posting useful information